# Interpretation of (diagonalized) inverse covariance matrix

Tags: covariance, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

There are several threads here about covariance matrix and inverse covariance matrix interpretation ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10795/how-to-interpret-an-inverse-covariance-or-precision-matrix), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73463/what-does-the-inverse-of-covariance-matrix-say-about-data-intuitively?rq=1) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140056/decomposition-of-inverse-covariance-matrix)).

However, I was wondering how to interpret the inverse covariance matrix (or precision matrix) as the covariance matrix can be diagonalized (since it's a definite positive matrix).
$$
 \Sigma = P D P^{-1}
$$
($\Sigma$ being the covariance matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix).
Then 
$$
 \Sigma^{-1} = P D^{-1} P^{-1}
$$

How to interpret this diagonal precision matrix $D^{-1}$ ? I think I don't get exactly the signification of the eigenvectors $P$ .

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The eigenvectors are the same in both cases--$P$ and $P^{-1}$ play their roles in both formulas--and therefore are subject to exactly the same interpretations. Which part don't you "get exactly"?

Comment: What I don't get is the signification of a covariance matrix when this matrix is diagonal. And also the signification of the inverse covariance matrix when this matrix is diagonal.

Comment: I think your last comment clarified what you were asking; this was not very clear in your original question. Please see my answer below.